# How to extract a substring from a string stored in a variable, based on a start / stop character

Tags: string, bash, shell, character

In the first line I'm after the value **64** and **F2DD65**

I want to catch the first variable by reading data from from a string in a variable, first from the beginning of the line untill the `:` character, and read the other variable from after the `#` character and 6 characters forward.
Is this possible?

This is the string:

```
var="64: (242,221,101) #F2DD65 srgb(242,221,101)"
```

my end result would be stored in variables:
`var1="64"`
`var2="F2DD65"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
var1=${var%%:*}
var2=${var##*#}
var2=${var2%% *}
```

Reference: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rn 's/(^.*)(\:.*#)(.*)([[:space:]].*$)/\1 - \3/p' <<< "64: (242,221,101) #F2DD65 srgb(242,221,101)"
```

With sed, split the line into sections using regular expressions (-r). Substitute the line for the relevant section (the first and then third separated with a -.

```
 awk -F [:#\ ] '{ print $1" - "$5 }'  <<< "64: (242,221,101) #F2DD65 srgb(242,221,101)"
```

With awk, split the line based on a :, a # and a space as delimiters. Print the 1st and 5th delimited fields with a - in between.

Answer (score 0):

With bash regular expressions:

```
var="64: (242,221,101) #F2DD65 srgb(242,221,101)"
re="^([^:]+): .* #([[:xdigit:]]+)"
if [[ $var =~ $re ]]; then
    var1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    var2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
else
    # String isn't the right format
    echo Fail
fi
```